# leaflet-> enable/disable statement "easybutton"

Tags: leaflet

I am using EasyButton plugin of leaflet ([link](https://github.com/CliffCloud/Leaflet.EasyButton)). More specifically I applied EasyBar which unites several buttons.
Plus, at certain zoom levels, I add/remove various layers with zoomend function ([link](http://leafletjs.com/reference.html#map-zoomend)). 
Is it possible to apply a function in which I can refer to BOTH button and zoom level?
*I don't know the formal code way but the idea something like the following:*

```
  map.on('zoomend', onZoomend);
    function onZoomend(){
        if(map.getZoom()<8) else if btn2.enable(){}};
```

**and here is my code:

```
map.on('zoomend', onZoomend);
function onZoomend(){

    if(map.getZoom()<8)(){
    map.addControl(info0);
    map.removeControl(info1);       
    map.removeControl(info2);   
    map.removeControl(info3); 
}       

    if(map.getZoom()==8){
    map.addControl(info1);      
    map.removeControl(info2);   
    map.removeControl(info3);   
    }           };
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not well versed in Leaflet but it looks like you could use their [DomUtil](http://leafletjs.com/reference.html#domutil) *hasClass* method to inspect whether or not the button has the 'enabled' or 'disabled' class present. Taking a look at the EasyButton github it looks like those classes get added when *enable()* or *disable()* is called, respectively.

Here are the enable() and disable() functions [directly from the EasyButton GitHub](https://github.com/CliffCloud/Leaflet.EasyButton/blob/master/src/easy-button.js#L280):

```
enable: function(){
    L.DomUtil.addClass(this.button, 'enabled');
    L.DomUtil.removeClass(this.button, 'disabled');
    this.button.setAttribute('aria-hidden', 'false');
    return this;
  },

  disable: function(){
    L.DomUtil.addClass(this.button, 'disabled');
    L.DomUtil.removeClass(this.button, 'enabled');
    this.button.setAttribute('aria-hidden', 'true');
    return this;
  }
```

Using your example, it might look like this:

`map.on('zoomend', onZoomend);
    function onZoomend(){
        // Do something only if zoom is less than 8 AND button2 has the 
        // 'enabled' class
        if(map.getZoom()<8) && L.DomUtil.hasClass(this.btn2,'enabled'){
            // Your logic
        }};`

It's worth noting that it looks like the 'enabled' and 'disabled' classes don't exist until either of the methods is called at least once.

Comment: Thank you @AHigh for your answer, but still not working...    I tried with --->    else if (L.DomUtil.HasClass(btn2,'enabled'))

Comment: What was the result? The method is hasClass (lower-case 'h').

Comment: It crashes. I tried with corrected lower-case version too.

Comment: I've edited my answer, you might need to qualify the button class with a 'this'.

Comment: I agree with you the fact that it has to be something with  "DomUtil hasClass method". Nevertheless, it still does not work with the edited version.